# AVAudioSession Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am trying to write a swift iOS app that will record the users voice. I have wrote the following code in swift however it fails to request mic permissions from the user. It prints granted yet it never records audio and in the settings pane under privacy it does not list the app. How do I request recording permissions in swift?

```
var session: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
session.requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
     if granted {
          println(" granted")
          session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
          session.setActive(true, error: nil)
          self.recorder.record()
     }else{
          println("not granted")
     }
})
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since iOS 7 you need check if it responds to selector `requestRecordPermission:`

I've tested this code using an **iPhone 5S** with **iOS 8 Beta** and it works perfectly. Once you grant permission, the system won't ask for it again.

It's worth saying that it didn't ask for permission when using the **Simulator**.

This is the code I've tried and is working:

```
if (session.respondsToSelector("requestRecordPermission:")) {
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
        if granted {
            println("granted")
            session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)
            session.setActive(true, error: nil)
            self.recorder ()
        } else{
            println("not granted")
        }
     })

}
```

Comment: I did check in the line before which I did not post and it didn't work... Probably because I was using the simulator. I have tried loading onto my device however there is a bug where it says it is unsupported(many radars have been already filed by others as well). Thank you for testing on your device.

Answer (score 5):

For `Swift 3`:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    if (session.responds(to: #selector(AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission(_:)))) {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
            if granted {
                Linphone.manager.callUser(username: username)

                print("granted")

                do {
                    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                    try session.setActive(true)
                }
                catch {

                    print("Couldn't set Audio session category")
                }
            } else{
                print("not granted")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5

```
var session: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
@IBAction func btnmike(_ sender: Any) {
   // let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    if (session.responds(to: #selector(AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission(_:)))) {
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
            if granted {
                print("granted")

                do {
                    try self.session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
                    try self.session.setActive(true)
                }
                catch {

                    print("Couldn't set Audio session category")
                }
            } else{
                print("not granted")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: In xcode 10.1 I had to change ```session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)``` to ```session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [])```