# Xcode not showing microphone access alert for iphonex simulator

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, iphone-x, xcode10.1

In Xcode, Before every time I got alert to access microphone.

[image]

Someone suggested below terminal command to avoid that

```
tccutil reset Microphone
```

After execution of this command, microphone usage alert not coming…so in iPhoneX simulator every time crashing in random place.

How to get above microphone usage alert every time like before? If this alert come then not crash…

In system settings now Xcode not visible under microphone 
[image]

How to get microphone usage alert every time like before ? For iphone5 simulator this alert coming sometime..if alert come then no crash..if not come then crash in random place...now in same xcode, microphone alert not coming for iphonex simulator....how to get it everytime ?

Comment: i think your question has answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318791/avaudiosession-swift

Comment: @justicepenny in my case not using requestRecordPermission code...strange